# How to keep the state after re-fetching data in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux toolkit inside my app.I have a datatable that is showing some data in rows. Each row has 2 buttons; one is "analyze" the other one is "do stuff", "do stuff" should only be enabled if "analyze" is clicked. The state of "analyze" is being tracked on the backend, thus when I click "analyze" it dispatches an async thunk named "postAnalyze" to the backend and sets the corresponding value to true; it is named as "isAnalyzed". At the same time this returns me a set of data that I should display on the modal when I click "do stuff", this returned object has an id that corresponds to the id of the item on my data table, . So far, I have told backend to set the isAnalyzed state on the data that I am showing on my datatable to "true". I have now a second async thunk that fetches all the data from the back end to show on my data table. It is called "getAllStuff()".

My issue is I am not able to make the data persist when I open the modal. For example, I clicked on "analyze", meanwhile I am setting  "isAnalyzed" to true, I can succesfully show the data on the modal, but if I click "analyze" on another row, it succesfully fetches the data but this time it multiplies the entry; for instance; my modal has three inputs that shows the returned data, whenever I click on another "doStuff" these datas are multiplied.

```
.addCase(postInvestigationById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = "idle";
            debugger;
            if (action.payload.resultType === ResultType.Ok) {
            
                const objectId = action.payload.data.OBJECTNAME.id; // Find existing item by the id, I am using this id to find the index of the corresponding data on the datatable
                const index = state.mermiBasvuruCombinedResponse.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === objectId );
                if (index !== -1) {
                    state.dataTableObjectResponse.items[index].isAnalyzed= true;
                    state.allInvestigation.push({ ...action.payload.data });
                }
            }
        })
```

On the above code, I am trying to set the returned analyze data to the corresponding data on the data table based on their "id". However, I am stuck and unable tothink  forward how to tackle this.